# Moving a sub-directory into the parent of the main directory in C#

Tags: c#, file

I'm looking to figure out how to move a directory out of its parent, into its parents, parent. It sounds a little odd, so I'll visualize it. We have Folder A, B, C, C Being in B, etc. I need to move folder C out of B, and into directory A.

I've already attempted it using this (extractPath is folder A, FolderB is, well folder B):

```
Directory.Move(Directory.GetDirectories(extractPath + @"\FolderB")[0],Directory.GetParent(extractPath + @"\FolderB").ToString());
```

However from this error, it appears to be trying to move it:
System.IO.IOException: 'The file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\ExampleFile.png' already exists.'

I should be using Path.Combine rather than adding the two, but I just need it to work, I'll fix that later.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I rewrote my code to be easier to read, and probably lower the chance of me messing something up

```
String newDir = Directory.GetDirectories(extractPath + @"\FolderB")[0]; //Should return folder C
Directory.Move(newDir, extractPath); //Moves folder C to folder A.
``
```

Comment: From the remarks section of the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-6.0), `If you try to move a directory to a directory that already exists, an IOException will occur.`  which seems to be what is happening here.  Make sure that the directory C does not exist under A.  If it does exist, move the contents by enumerating the files and directories from the source directory (B->C) into the target directory (A->C).

Comment: @hijinxbassist So, is moving the directory basically replacing the directory, because I'm trying to move Directory C as a subdirectory of Directory A? If it's replacing it, I would need it to move to FolderA\FolderC

Comment: The directory C cannot exist under A prior to using Move.

Comment: @hijinxbassist But the whole point is that C is a sub directory to a, so if I cant use move to move it out, since its a sub-directory of A, meaning its under A, how do i move it up and into A? I need to be at least guided in the right direction with some advice.

Comment: I meant a direct subdirectory of A.   If you have source path "A\B\C" and want to move "A\B\C" to "A\C", "A\C" cannot already exist as a directory.  If "A\C" already exists and you want to move the contents of "A\B\C" to "A\C", you will need to enumerate the directories and files from your source path and copy them into the destination path.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! It was a combination of a few minor details but the main issue is this:

I had

```
Directory.Move(newDir, extractPath);
```

You've got to add the name of the file of newDir, my original folder im moving.
You can get the name of just that folder with

```
Path.GetFileName(newDir);
```

You will then have

```
Directory.Move(newDir, extractPath + Path.GetFileName(newDir));
```